# NoClassDefFoundError for libs added in Android Lib Project

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-library, android-testing

I have a Android Lib Project which has a number of libraries (jars) added in /lib folder. 
Now, I have written a Android Test Project to test the APIs of the Library project and I added the jar of the Lib project inside this test project.

Everything complies fine but when the code, in the Library project executes, which uses the jar file, I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError.

Could someone please help me with  this issue?
Please do let me know what other details would be required from my end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean Project and Run it again.

Comment: Did you use latest Library project? Please check.

Comment: yes i am using the latest version of my lib project

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

Right click on your project --> select Build Path --> go to Order and Export Tab

[image]

Check all the libs you added here and done.